# jQuery - change value of an input of the previous div

Tags: jquery

I have this kind of code :

```
function changeValue(el) {

}

<div class="tracklistOff">
    ...

    <div class="sideon">
        ...
    </div>

    <div class="trackon">
        ...
    </div>

    <div class="sideon">
        ...
    </div>

    <div class="trackon">
        ...
    </div>

    <div class="sideon">
        <span class="sideindex"><input type="hidden" name="sidesOriginal[]" value="#" /></span>
    </div>

    <div class="trackon">
        <span class="trackbotton"><a href="#" onClick="changeValue(this);return false">Edit</a></span>
    </div>

    <div class="sideon">
        ...
    </div>

    <div class="trackon">
        ...
    </div>

    <div class="sideon">
        ...
    </div>

    <div class="trackon">
        ...
    </div>        

    ...
</div>
```

and i'd like to change the value of sidesOriginal[] to "hello" by clicking on Edit and using only the *this* reference as starting position. I'll change only that value, on the previous *sideon*, not for each *sideon*. How can I do it in jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/peeter/qy3h9/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).parent().parent().children('.sideon').children('input[type="hidden"]').val('hello');
```

Comment: yeah I thought about this solution, but I hope in a way more easy, without scroll all parents :)